# How to display UIWebView content at the center of my view?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, splash-screen

I have an UIWebview which taking all the place in my View. My content are in the top but I don't change the code of my UIWebview content and I would like to display my UIWebview at the center of my view (in position 2) for all the device (IOS6/IOS7), how can I do that with the good parameter or manipulation in my UIWebview ?

I work with xib file.
I don't use AutoLayout for my view.

[image: My situation actually]

Thanks for advance

Comment: you can read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraints/WorkingwithConstraints.html. for aligning views. with proper constraints.

Comment: I don't use autoLayout, sorry

Comment: Just adjust the center of your UIWebVew frame to the center of the view in ViewDidLoad: webView.center = self.view.center;

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programattically as...

```
CGRect viewrect = view.bounds.

webview.center = CGPointMake(viewrect.size.width/2,viewrect.size.height/2);
```

Try it out.